# Рандомное число, меняющееся каждые несколько дней HTML

Tags: javascript, html, случайные-числа

Задача такая:

Есть число дней N [7..9].
Есть число M [0..2].

Задается рандомное M от 0 до 2 и отображается в строчке на сайте. Задается рандомное число дней N от 7 до 9. Спустя N дней число M снова задается рандомно и меняется на сайте. В этот же момент генерируется новое число N. Далее цикл повторяется.

Как можно осуществить?

Comment: такое лучше на серверной части делать, если вам надо действительно _через N дней_

Comment: через cookies, ставишь им lifetime неделю, и добавляешь метод isset который будет проверять не пропала ли переменная